# How to Content Loader used in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, loader, server-side-rendering

In Server Side Rendering (SSR), how will used in content loader. First the content loader skeleton will come after get response from server loader will hide.

Comment: SSR means you will send a html string to the browser to parse and render. since its already sending the html in the first place, you cant send some pre-data to show skeleton. at max you can use JS onload function

Comment: Can you share any sample code...